# Is there a way to output a (symbolic) matrix equation in matlab similar to one in LaTex?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I was wondering if there was a way to use defined Matrices to print them in an expression either using live editor or the normal editor. I was hoping to get my output to look similar to the image I have attached. I am hoping to get that as an output, but can only get individual matrices per line with the 'ans =' in between [image: The image here]

Answer (score 1):

My solution is also a workaround but I think it works in a better way:

```
clear
syms x y z

% create symbolic variables (could be calculated also)
A = sym([-2  1 -3; -3  2 -2; -1 -3 -1])
b = [x; y; z]
v = sym([-3; -4; 3])

% convert to latex strings
A_str = latex(A)
b_str = latex(b)
v_str = latex(v)

my_Eqn = append(A_str, b_str, " = ", v_str)  % create desired line

% replace [ and ] since "MATLAB Latex" does not seem to support them
% and add $-signs to mark it as a Latex string
my_Eqn = "$" + replace(my_Eqn,["[";"]"], ["(";")"]) + "$"

figure(1); clf; hold on  % create figure
text(0, 0.5, my_Eqn, 'interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 20)  % write text
set(gca,'visible','off')  % remove axis
```

Output:

[image: Equation image]

The downside is the size of the figure and the space that is wasted in this way.

It is also to mention that precalculated fomulas can be inserted in the LIVE EDITOR. Just convert one line  to "Text" and under INSERT > Equation an equation can be pasted (even latex)

Answer (score 0):

**In Progress: Inviting anyone to build upon this and edit as they please.*

### Code so far:

This example uses a `.mlx` live script. Casting the matrices as `sym`, symbolic matrices will force the output to display brackets. To configure the output to display square brackets the `sympref()`, symbolic preferences function can be called to set the `'MatrixWithSquareBrackets'` to `true`.

[image: Live Script Output]

```
sympref('MatrixWithSquareBrackets',true);
syms x y z 
Matrix_1 = sym([-2  1 -3; -3  2 -2; -1 -3 -1]);
Matrix_2 = [x; y; z];
Matrix_3 = sym([-3; -4; 3]);

disp(Matrix_1); disp(Matrix_2); disp("="); disp(Matrix_3);
```